# Call one shell script with another

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

If I have a program that multiplies the user-supplied value with 10, how do I write another bash script that has arguments passed to it and takes these arguments and collects the output of the other program and organizes it into a table?

For example:

```
    [user]$ table 1 5
    #
    #Value  Result
     1      10
     5      50
    [user]$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
tenTimes(){
  expr "$1" \* 10
}

table(){
  printf '%s\t%s\n' \#Value Result
  for a; do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$a" "$(tenTimes "$a")"
  done
}

table 1 5
```

Output:

```
#Value  Result
1   10
5   50
```

Comment: if my tenTimes script is in /home/user/sim/ but my table script is located in /home/user/scrips/ , how do I call the tenTimes script in the table script?

Comment: You run your tenTimes script in exactly the same way you would any other program or script.  It has to be set executable (`chmod +x`), and it has to be either in your $PATH or you need to specify the full pathname to the script (e.g. `/home/user/sim/tenTimes` rather just `tenTimes`)

Comment: `/home/user/sim/tenTimes` or have `/home/user/sim/` be a component of your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Relative paths should work also, but you should cd into `dirname "$0"` (the path of your currently executing script) before you use them or graft them onto that path.

Comment: btw, if you intend to write a lot of scripts, it's useful to have a `~/bin` directory and add that to your PATH.  Then `mv` or `cp` your scripts to `~/bin`

Answer (score 0):

You can it through a shell interpreter with an absolute or relative path;

```
/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/script
/usr/sbin/ksh ~/script
```

Maybe you want to use some functions much like an included library;

```
#!/bin/sh
func_a() { echo $(($1%42)); }
```

And in another file:

```
#!/bin/sh
. ~/path/to/func_a_file
func_a
```

Or maybe you want to call the script while assigning the results as a variable:

```
var1=$(~/path/to/script)
```